# PayPal configuration

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment

I do PayPal integration, and I'm having two issues.

1. In the settings of pay button you can specify a fixed price or drop-down list with a variety products and prices. How to make button (or URL address) for ufixed price? To be able select price before sending.
2. How to automatically receive notification of successful payment? Server must run the script, but only in case successful payment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Buy now button can let your customers to enter their preferred amount and then pay you. You can leave a blank in the amount field when you create Buy Now button on your PayPal account.
2. You can integrate PayPal IPN to reach this requirement.
   https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/